# Why has this particular TimeSpan format string stopped working in .NET 4?

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, .net-4.0, timespan

Consider this code (prestuffed with an example):

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse("7/30/2010 9:33:29.1234567 AM");
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse("6/30/2010 9:33:00.7654321 AM");

TimeSpan ts = dt1 - dt2;

Console.WriteLine(string.Format( "{0:d.hh:mm:ss.ff}", ts ));
```

This is representative of a piece of code that I've had working since .NET 1.1 at least.

It worked fine in 1.1 through 3.5 with the following output (for these dummied up inputs):

```
30.00:00:28.3580246
```

But now I'm seeing that it dies in .NET 4 with the error message:

`Input string was not in a correct format.`

So it's as if .NET 4 has suddenly decided it doesn't like this format for time differences. Changing the line to, say

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format( "{0}", ts.ToString("d.hh:mm:ss.ff") ));
```

has the same effect.

Now the thing I've noticed is that if I just do the default `.ToString()` I get the same output. I believe the thought process was that this was an insurance policy against the default format changing in a future version. But now it doesn't look like that's even an option.

Does anyone know why this changed and if I'm doing something wrong or if there's a best practices way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [configuration switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee803802.aspx) to restore the old behaviour of [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx).

Comment: So basically that format string's been doing nothing all this time. Outstanding. Thanks.

Comment: @Schnapple Exactly. In .NET 3.5 and earlier, the `TimeSpan` struct wasn't `IFormattable`. When `string.Format` and related methods see something like `{0:something}` and the argument supplied isn't `IFormattable`, they have nowhere to put that format string, and they just discard it. That's what happened in your code until .NET 4.0 arrived.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the configuration switch is a format change that is compatible with previous versions.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format( "{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss.ff}", ts ));
```

This solution is detail [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/525660df-0c0f-4816-a5bb-fa5896224189).

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the composite format string you've been using in your code **did not have any effect at all**, because `TimeSpan` **does not** support custom format strings (.NET <  4.0).

*i.e.* Your TimeSpan would have always been formatted like `30.00:00:28.3580246` regardless of format string.

From MSDN:

> In previous versions of the .NET Framework, the TimeSpan structure did
> not implement IFormattable and did not support format strings.
>
> However, **many developers mistakenly assumed that TimeSpan did support
> a set of format strings** and used them in composite formatting
> operations with methods such as String.Format. Ordinarily, if a type
> implements IFormattable and supports format strings, calls to
> formatting methods with unsupported format strings usually throw a
> FormatException. However, because TimeSpan did not implement
> IFormattable, the runtime ignored the format string and instead called
> the TimeSpan.ToString() method. **This means that, although the format
> strings had no effect on the formatting operation, their presence did
> not result in a FormatException.**

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by Mitch Wheat and Saeb Amini in [their](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3373186/117870) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25491277/117870), `TimeSpan` does not implement `IFormattable` prior to .NET 4.0. Consequently, format strings have **no effect** on the `TimeSpan.ToString()` output since they were ignored.

> However, because TimeSpan did not implement IFormattable, *the runtime **ignored the format string** and instead called the TimeSpan.ToString method*. This means that, although the format strings had no effect on the formatting operation, their presence did not result in a FormatException.
>
> [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee803802%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

That said, fi you desire to format a `TimeSpan` value across all versions of the .NET framework, it is much better to convert the `TimeSpan` value to `DateTime` and then format that result as shown below:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse("7/30/2010 9:33:29.1234567 AM");
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse("6/30/2010 9:33:00.7654321 AM");

TimeSpan ts = dt1 - dt2;

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:d.hh:mm:ss.ff}", new DateTime(ts.Ticks))) 
// prints 30.00:00:28.36
```

Answer (score 0):

I've pasted your piece of code and it seems to be a culture problem :

with .NET 2 an FormatException is thrown too

If I specified the us culture (culture is fr-FR by default) , the code works :

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse("7/30/2010 9:33:29.1234567 AM", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

You can also specified an Invariant culture to ignore the culture

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse("7/30/2010 9:33:29.1234567 AM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I think you're on to something with the culture but, but it's not the DateTime lines that are giving me fits, it's the TimeSpan format string. Even if I specify the culture in the TimeSpan ToString and both of the DateTime.Parse methods, I'm still getting the same.